# Python Class: moving rectangle

Tags: python

Hello I'm trying to make this rectangle move to certain co-ordinates without changing the width and height of the rectangle. When I use the `__str__` method I'm not getting the right answer. Any Ideas what's going wrong? Here's my code

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self,corner,width,height):
    self._x = corner[0]
    self._y = corner[1]
    self._width = width
    self._height = height

def get_bottom_right(self):
    self._width = self._x + self._width
    self._height = self._y + self._height
    return(self._width,self._height)

def move(self,p):
    self._p = self._x, self._y

def resize(self,width,height):
    resize = self._width + self._height
    return(resize)


def __str__(self):
    return '({0}, {1})'.format((self._x, self._y), (self._x + self._width, self._y + self._height))
```

Comment: What is the "right answer"? What answer are you getting? Show us the inputs you're giving your `Rectangle` instance.

Comment: As a side note, if you're having problems getting the hang of changing state, maybe you should first try to write non-mutating functions, like a `moved(self, p)` that returns a new `Rectangle` that's this one moved to `p`. It can be easier to think through what's happening in a `return Rectangle(…)` than in a `self._foo = …`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `move()` function looks wrong. It takes one parameter named `p` (for "pair", I assume), and I would assume it's supposed to move the rectangle to those coordinates. But it isn't changing `self._x` or `self._y` at all. I think you've gotten your assignment backwards in that function, and you probably meant to do:

```
def move(self,p):
    self._x, self._y = p
```

That's if p is a tuple (a `(3,4)` pair). If it's an object with `x` and `y` attributes, you'll want to do:

```
def move(self,p):
    self._x = p.x
    self._y = p.y
```

as someone else has already pointed out.

Actually, your code has several other problems in addition to this one. Your `get_bottom_right()` function is changing the value of `self._width` and `self._height`, which is not what you intend, and your `resize()` function *isn't* changing the value of `self._width` and `self._height` at all.

... I see others have pointed out the errors in your `move()` and `resize()` functions, so I'll tackle the `get_bottom_right()` function. You probably want to do this:

```
def get_bottom_right(self):
    right = self._x + self._width
    bottom = self._y + self._height
    return (right,bottom)
```

Notice how I only changed the variable names, but left your code otherwise the same. This will do what you want, *without* changing your rectangle's width and height in the process. Your original code would have changed the width and height every time you called `get_bottom_right()`.

Comment: Yes that worked for me. Thank you! I see now that my functions did nothing at all haha

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to move your rectangle, but I do know that your `move` and `resize` methods are currently not doing anything.

Currently, what you're move method is doing is accepting a parameter called `p`, which it then proceeds to ignore. It then creates a new field inside your rectangle called `_p`, and sets `_p` equal to its x and y coordinates. However, this is also a useless operation since you never end up using `_p` and because you never ended up actually moving the variable.

Instead, you may want to do something like this:

```
def move(self, x, y):
    self._x = x
    self._y = y
```

Now, if you do `my_rectangle.move(3, 4)`, the x and y coordinates of `my_rectangle` will be changed to 3 and 4.

If `p` is meant to be something like a "point" object, you probably want to do this instead:

```
def move(self, p):
    self._x = p.x
    self._y = p.y
```

Similarly, your "resize" method doesn't do anything meaningful. Calling it will simply return the sum of the width and the heights of your rectangle, which doesn't really mean anything. You probably want to change it to this instead:

```
def resize(self, width, height):
    self._width = width
    self._height = height
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `move` method doesn't modify the right attributes to move your rectangle. Instead of assigning to `self._p`, you want to use the `p` parameter passed in to modify `self._x` and `self._y`.

Try this:

```
def move(self,p):
     self._x, self._y = p
```

This moves the rectangle to be at point `p` (assuming `p` is an `(x,y)` tuple). If you want to move *by* `p` instead, try:

```
def move(self,p):
     self._x += p[0]
     self._y += p[1]
```

You have a similar issue in the `resize` method (where you want to modify `self._width` and `self._height`, rather than adding them together and returning them). The `get_bottom_right` method has the opposite problem, as it modifies `self._width` and `self._height` when it probably should not.